# How do I lower my toxic level?

Tags: system-shock-2

I inspected a pile of worms for too long and now I have a toxic level 1, which means I'm taking damage slowly but constantly. Surgical units and various healing items I could find restore health but do not decrease your toxic level.

Do I have to spend 10 nanites and die, or can I do something about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anti-Toxin hypos can reduce your toxin level.  You will sometimes find them laying about, or you could hit up a replicator.  [This FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/185706-system-shock-2/faqs/27508) has a list of replicator locations which can probably aid you in finding the closest one that stocks the hypos.

Or you could just die, I mean, that's always an option.  Just throwing it out there...

Comment: I visited a surgical unit, paid 5 nanites, toxic level remained intact.

Comment: @badp, it's been a long time.  Trying to find something to corroborate my...  14 year old memories of this game :P

Comment: @badp, whelp, can't find it, so I must be remembering wrong.  Edited out.

Comment: it has been a long time ago, but anti-toxin hypos should indeed do the trick. http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/pc/sysshock2/items.shtml